# select two items from rss in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, rss

how can i select two items from xml rss file

following code getting one item at a time i want to get two items  at a time

what should i put in select to select the second item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" />

  <xsl:template match="/rss/channel">
    <div class="RSS_Gadget">

  <div class="RSS_Content">
        <ul id="widget">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item"    />
     <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item" mode="extra"    />-->

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
<li>
  <xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </xsl:element>
  <div class="RSS_Body" >
    <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
  </div>

</li>
```

Comment: Please also provide an example of the required output. It's hard to guess what you mean by "get two items at a time".

Answer (score 2):

**Replace this code**:

```
  <xsl:template match="/rss/channel"> 
    <div class="RSS_Gadget"> 

  <div class="RSS_Content"> 
        <ul id="widget"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item"    /> 
     <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item" mode="extra"    />--> 

    </ul> 
  </div> 
</div> 
  </xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="item"> 
<li> 
  <xsl:element name="a"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="href"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="link"/> 
    </xsl:attribute> 
    <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute> 
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/> 
  </xsl:element> 
  <div class="RSS_Body" > 
    <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes" /> 
  </div> 

 </li>
</xsl:template>
```

**with**:

```
  <xsl:template match="/rss/channel"> 
    <div class="RSS_Gadget"> 

  <div class="RSS_Content"> 
        <ul id="widget"> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() mod 2 = 1]"    /> 
    </ul> 
  </div> 
</div> 
  </xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="item"> 
<li> 
  <xsl:element name="a"> 
    <xsl:attribute name="href"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="link"/> 
    </xsl:attribute> 
    <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute> 
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/> 
  </xsl:element> 
  <div class="RSS_Body" > 
    <xsl:value-of select="description" disable-output-escaping="yes" /> 
  </div> 

 </li> 

 <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item[1]" mode="extra"/>
</xsl:template>
```

**Explanation**:

This instruction:

```
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item[position() mod 2 = 1]"    />
```

Applies templates to the first `item` element of every pair of two adjacent `item` siblings (to the `1st`, `3rd`, ... `2k+1st`  `item` child).

Then in the template that matches an `item` element, after the matched element is processed another template is applied to/for-processing its immediate following sibling:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item[1]" mode="extra"/>
```

**Note**: It is highly probable that you don't need to use DOE (the `disable-output-escaping` attribute) in your code. Always try to avoid using DOE, because it isn't a mandatory feature of XSLT (not all XSLT processors support and implement it) and its use breaks up the XSLT architectural model.

Comment: <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item[1]" mode="extra"/>
 does not apply to <li> it just displays the text without the <li> template

Comment: *No* template matches `li` -- the templates are matching `item`. You need to have: `<xslt:template match="item" mode="extra"><li> Whatever... </li></xsl:template>`. It all depends on how you want the pair of `item`s to be processed and what to be generated -- something that you missed to say in your question...

Comment: i want one <li> tag with two <a></a> tags to be generated

Comment: Our field, fortunately, is precise -- there is no place for emotions and judging any help as "rude" isn't going to lead anywhere. Yes, the truth in many cases can feel painful. Please, try to overcome the initial passionate reaction and to think *logically*. Didn't two more people also point in their comments that you haven't provided essential, needed information for this question to be answered? @FailedDev said: "*Please provide .xml input*". Dabbler said: "*Please also provide an example of the required output. It's hard to guess what you mean by "get two items at a time*"